# How to insert data into a custom object with lookup field from apex controller

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have a custom object `MyCustomObj__c` which has a field called "ContactData".

I am trying to insert a record into the custom object with the following apex method. It gives an error:

```
Invalid ID
```

The value `Hari` already exists in the Contact list.

**apex code:**

```
public static String saveData(){
    MyCustomObj__c newObj = new MyCustomObj__c(); 
    newObj.contactData__c = 'Hari';
    insert newObj;
    return "success";
}
```

How do I insert a row?

Comment: Hi @Hari, there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should pass ID of contact record 'Hari'

```
 public static String saveData(){
       MyCustomObj__c newObj = new MyCustomObj__c(); 
       newObj.contactData__c = [SELECT Id 
                                FROM Contact 
                                WHERE Name ='Hari' LIMIT 1].Id;
       insert newObj;
       return "success";
 }
```

Sure, you should try to avoid SOQL here, it's just example.

Answer (score 0):

**Apex Code to insert data into an object:**

```
static void testInsert(){
    User testUser = new User(username = 'joebieber@hotmail.com', 
    firstname = 'joe', lastname = 'bieber', 
    email = 'joebieber@hotmail.com', Alias = 'jo', 
    CommunityNickname = 'jo', 
    TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York', LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
    EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1', 
    ProfileId = '00e6000000167RPAAY', 
    LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US');
    insert testUser;

    List<SObject> sos = Database.query('select username from User');

    List<User> users= new List<User>();
    if( sos != null ){
       for(SObject s : sos){
          if (((User)s).get('username') == 'joebieber@hotmail.com')
            Utils.log('' + ((User)s).get('username') );
       }
    }
}
```

Should print the username of the user you just added.

Answer (score 0):

We can use data loader for moving data to database for lookup field
Guru

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. [Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)